# Designing a domain model (class diagram) for a financial software

Tags: uml, domain-driven-design, abstract-class, class-diagram, domain-model

During my preparation for an exam in software engineering, I came across the following task in an old exam:

For a client, you create a new financial software whose task is, among other things, to perform tax calculations. The following requirements have been communicated to you by the Client:

- The system must be able to:

  - calculate and display VAT for different countries and tax rates (Germany 19%, Austria 20%, Switzerland 8%).
  - calculate and display the income tax according to country-specific tax tables (separate table for Germany, Austria, Switzerland).
- The system must allow the user to:

  - enter the tax relevant data (gross amount for VAT, annual income for income tax)
  - print the result of the tax calculation on a network printer.
  - send the result of the tax calculation to the appropriate tax office.

**Task 1**: Capture the requirements communicated by the client in a domain model (class diagram) with the following information: classes, attributes, methods, relationships, multiplicities, relationship name.

**Solution:**
I am not sure how to define the right classes, relationships and multiplicities. But I tried it and came to the following incomplete solution:
[image: Solution for first Task:]

**First Update:**

[image: Solution for first Task:]

**Second Update:**

[image]

Could someone help me with this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Review of your diagram

I propose you to read your first diagram, and leave it as an exercise to cross-check if it really meets the requirements:

- "A tax rate is composed of a country" (top composition). So countries do not exist independently of tax codes.  Is this really what you meant? And does anything in the requirements tell that there is only one tax rate per country?
- "A tax rate is composed of an (optional) income tax rate, and an (optional) VAT rate" (double composition in the middle). Ouh!?
- "Every income tax rate has its own tax category(ies)" (bottom composition).  Isn't the idea of categories to group similar income tax rates?
- "A tax rate aggregates tax administrations, and a tax administration may appear in several aggregates" (aggregation).  Why should an administration be aggregated in tax codes?

**First recommentation:**  read in your course the difference between association, aggregation and composition.   THe use of aggreegation and composition are in principle exceptional and there must be strong reasons to use use it.

Some more questions:

- Where are the names of the relations?
- What requirement justifies the tax administration? If it is justified, should'nt it be related to a country?
- Is printing some elements really part of the domain model or does it already belong to some user-interface?

**Second recommendation:** only show elements taht you can reasonably derive from the requirements, and avoid any user-interface related behaviors.

**Edit:** your final diagram following our exchanges in the comment section represents much better what you wanted to represent initially.  You could add the multiplicity 1..* rate for 1 category.  You could also add a separator, in order to show classes consistently with a property and operation sections, even if one of the two is empty.  The design is still basic,  since all properties/attributes are public which is not recommended (but for I suppose you did this to avoid a lot of extra getters/setters in your design).

## Alternate approach:

Your narrative describes one single use-case, which is *perform tax calculation* and consists of entering the calculation data, printing it and sending it.  The actors are probably some clerc of your customer and perhaps tax offices.

I find the following candidates for classes chronologically, when reading the narrative: VAT, country, tax rate, income tax,  "country-specific tax tables", gross amount, annual income, tax calculation, tax office. Let's have a closer look:

- Tax office is very unclear: is there a network printer per tax office? how is the relevant tax office determined? are there one office per country, or can the organisation be more complex?
- VAT and income tax are very different:

  - for VAT there are [different rates per country](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/sites/taxation/files/resources/documents/taxation/vat/how_vat_works/rates/vat_rates_en.pdf). The applicable rate is always known, and the calculation is based on the applicable rate and the gross value.
  - For income tax the narrative speaks of country-specific tax tables:  this means that the rate might not be known in advance, but depend on the taxable income level.   (e.g. in [Austria](https://europa.eu/youreurope/business/taxation/business-tax/company-tax-eu/austria/index_en.htm) there is a minimum, and beyond it's flat rate;  but in [France](https://europa.eu/youreurope/business/taxation/business-tax/company-tax-eu/france/index_fr.htm),  there is a normal rate, and a reduced rate for the first 500K€).  In reality, income tax is much more complicated, since it may also depend on the legal form of the enterprise, or what is done with the income (re-invested vs. distributed), but let's keep it simple for the exercise. The wording leaves an ambiguity whether there is one table per country or several.
  - You could nevertheless generalize the concept of tax, if you'd want, considering in this exercise, that its amount is calculated for a base amount (gross amount or annual income).
- The tax calculation is not fully clear:  is it just the user interface, or is the calculation actually some domain object. This would give us:

This would lead to a diagram like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, for your first question: would an association between Country and TaxRate solve the problem, so that at the end it looks like this [Country] 1 ___ 1 .. *[TaxRate]?to solve the second problem you mentioned, I replaced composition with inheritance. I'm trying now to correct the other errors on a diagram. I edited the diagram and updated it in the post. is this right so far?

Comment: Yes, a simple association is often the best. The multiplicity seems better as well (e.g.  [here](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/sites/taxation/files/resources/documents/taxation/vat/how_vat_works/rates/vat_rates_en.pdf) you can see that Autstria has a normal rate at 20, a reduced rate at 10,   but some countries have even a super-reduced rate, not to speak of changes of rate at a certain date).  Inheritance is an option for the second one.  But you can't calculate any tax without an amount.  So you have to fine-tune the API.  ANd probably category should be at the level of the rate

Comment: @AbdalrohmanAlsalkhadi As a general recommendation regarding stack overflow:  When you change the question significantly after an answer is posted, clarify in the question what you've changed, otherwhise people will see only last state of question and an answer which does no longer match the question and would seem irrelevant or wrong.  Best way,  is to leave the original diagram, and add the new diagram at the end , clarifying that it's the new version :-)

Comment: _names of the relation_? Did you mean role names instead?

Comment: @qwerty_so I was just rephrasing the "relationship name" in the instructions of task 1.  I guess the instructor was referring to the association's name but I cannot exclude that role names were meant.

Comment: @qwerty_so "relationship names" = the names that should appear on the arrows, is it clear?

Comment: @Christophe I have edited the diagram again

Comment: I replaced the method YearlyIncome() in "IncomeTaxRate" with IncomeTaxRate(). Secondly, I have connected the classes "TaxCategory" and "TaxRate" with each other by association instead of "IncomeTaxRate" by composition. Third, I added a parameter "gross" to the method CalculateTax() in the class "TaxRate.  @Christophe You wrote: "Is printing some elements really part of the domain model or does it already belong to some user-interface?" --> Do I have to delete the method "SendToPrinter()", if the Answer to your Question is "NO"? because I do think, that this belong to some user-interface.

Comment: @AbdalrohmanAlsalkhadi A relatiosship name is (in most cases) rather pointless. As a side note: ping-pong with questions is not the best you can do here. Plase stay put with a single question and do not add your stepwise answers to the question.

Comment: @qwerty_so thanks for the hint. What do you think about the last Solution, is there something wrong or missing?

Comment: You obviously did not read Christophes answer carefully.

Comment: @AbdalrohmanAlsalkhadi I edited the answer with a couple of last comments on your last diagram.  And I also added a section about an alternate approach,  in which I went through the narrative my way (but purposely not too far from yours), wiht some questions, not about UML but about the domain.  You'll note the association name,  in some case its role name, and most of all the efforts to harmonize API of taxes, isolating rates to the only case where it makes sense.  In case of residual doubt,  have a look [here](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html)

Comment: Your approach to analyzing the narrative is impressive. Now I know how I should approach similar tasks next time in order to get a correct solution. While I was working on the task, I lacked knowledge about the dependence of taxes on the amount of taxable income and I did not know how to present the country-specific tax tables in the diagram. As you have already mentioned, some things are not clear enough to draw a conclusion. Thank you very much for your efforts, you saved my day :-)

Comment: Btw, you saw through me when you assumed that I only have public properties/attributes because I wanted to avoid many additional getters/setters :-)

Comment: Does the diagram you created correspond to the strategy pattern? 
feel free to look at the question I asked earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64696125/designing-a-logical-view-and-strategy-pattern-from-a-class-diagram

Comment: @AbdalAlsal That's an interesting remark! I hadn't thought about it, even if the idea briefly crossed my mind for the income tax (because table based calculations depend from country to country).  But indeed, it looks like a strategy design pattern, with TaxCalculation being the context,  Tax being the abstract Strategy defining the interface for the Context,  and VAT and IncomeTax being concrete Strategies. But the intent does not fully fit:  I did this because both have a similar interface, and not to with the intent of using them interchangeably. So if it's strategy it's by accident :-)

Comment: @Christophe It is really admirable that you have modelled a design pattern without even knowing it. I only noticed it because I was trying to realize strategy patterns and noticed that the pattern is already there for the most part. I am still not sure what to do to meet all the requirements for the strategy pattern. But I think, the class "Tax" has to become an interface, which means that the subclasses "VAT" and "IncomeTax" have to implement all methods of "Tax", so "getTaxCode()" has to be implemented in both classes. what do you think about that?

Comment: @AbdalAlsal yes, this makes sense.

Comment: @AbdalAlsal That’s a design choice that is up to you.  you could as well use an abstract class that holds the common behaviour

Comment: @Christophe Thank you for Helping, that was very useful, I think I will do well in the exam tomorrow :-)